# Select particular text in HTML element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have to select particular word in div tag.

**HTML**

```
  <div>This is my text</div>
```

Here i need a select the word `my`.

Is it possible to achieve with CSS alone?

Comment: I think the answer will be "Nope" via CSS

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: No, unless that text is enclosed in a specific element, like a `span`.

Comment: It cannot be done with CSS, it can be done with Jquery or simple vanila Javascript.

Comment: Are  you trying to achieve text highlighting or something ? In that case you will gave to use javascript to search for the word and wrap it around a span and then give css to the span.

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div> This is <span id="myspan"> my </span> text </div>
```

CSS:

```
#myspan {
 ENTER CSS HERE 
}
```

there's no other chance (unless you change the span to any other tag)

Comment: I'm able to add any tag's there, i using this field for some other case.

Comment: okay that should work

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't select inner text via css...
You should use some javascript code or add a class to the specific text container.

Check jquery :contains selector, for example:
http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/